# SQL Display every class

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Can someone assist me with my Oracle SQL joins, something is missing.
The select statement below lists every Student and the Class Date but I want to show every Class for each Student, even if the Student took the Class or not.
Kim, Brandy and Trina, Brandy should have every class name listed with no Class Date since they have not took any class yet.
Green, Robert took 3 Classes and did not take 2 Classes, the 2 Classes should be listed also with no Class Date since he did not take them.
The insert statements and create tables are listed. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks

```
SELECT VW.STUDENT_NAME,
       VW.EMPLE_NO,
       CN.PK_CLASS_NAME_ID,
       CN.CLASS_NAME,
       DP.CLASS_DATE
  FROM EMPLOYEE_NAME  VW
       LEFT JOIN DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW DP ON DP.FK_CO_EMPL_ID = VW.EMPLE_NO
       LEFT JOIN TBL_CLASS_NAME_NEW CN
           ON CN.PK_CLASS_NAME_ID = DP.FK_CLASS_NAME_ID
ORDER BY STUDENT_NAME ASC;

CREATE TABLE TBL_CLASS_NAME_NEW
(
  PK_CLASS_NAME_ID  INTEGER,
  CLASS_NAME        VARCHAR2(75 BYTE)
);

Insert into TBL_CLASS_NAME_NEW
   (PK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_NAME)
 Values
   (1, 'CPR');
Insert into TBL_CLASS_NAME_NEW
   (PK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_NAME)
 Values
   (3, 'ETHICS');
Insert into TBL_CLASS_NAME_NEW
   (PK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_NAME)
 Values
   (4, 'HARRASEMENT');
Insert into TBL_CLASS_NAME_NEW
   (PK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_NAME)
 Values
   (5, 'DEFENSIVE TEST');
Insert into TBL_CLASS_NAME_NEW
   (PK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_NAME)
 Values
   (2, 'RANGE');
COMMIT;



CREATE TABLE DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
(
  PRODUCT_ID           NUMBER                   NOT NULL,
  FK_CO_EMPL_ID        NUMBER,
  FK_CLASS_NAME_ID     NUMBER,
  CLASS_DATE           DATE
);


Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (4, 4, 1, TO_DATE('7/18/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (22, 4, 1, TO_DATE('7/25/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (18, 4, 4, TO_DATE('7/18/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (21, 4, 3, TO_DATE('7/4/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (32, 22, 2, TO_DATE('8/15/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (34, 22, 1, TO_DATE('8/29/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (35, 22, 1, TO_DATE('7/4/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (46, 18, 4, TO_DATE('7/4/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (43, 18, 5, TO_DATE('7/11/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (45, 4, 2, TO_DATE('7/4/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (48, 4, 5, TO_DATE('7/11/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (51, 22, 3, TO_DATE('7/4/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (52, 18, 3, TO_DATE('7/18/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
Insert into DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
   (PRODUCT_ID, FK_CO_EMPL_ID, FK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CLASS_DATE)
 Values
   (5, 4, 2, TO_DATE('7/25/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_NAME
(
    EMPLE_NO        INTEGER,
    STUDENT_NAME    VARCHAR2 (100 BYTE),
    LAST_NAME       VARCHAR2 (40 BYTE),
    FIRST_NAME      VARCHAR2 (40 BYTE)
);

Insert into EMPLOYEE_NAME
   (EMPLE_NO, STUDENT_NAME, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
 Values
   (4, 'WENDY, FRANK', 'FRANK', 'WENDY');
Insert into EMPLOYEE_NAME
   (EMPLE_NO, STUDENT_NAME, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
 Values
   (22, 'JOHN, JAMES', 'JAMES', 'JOHN');
Insert into EMPLOYEE_NAME
   (EMPLE_NO, STUDENT_NAME, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
 Values
   (18, 'GREEN, ROBERT', 'ROBERT', 'GREEN');
Insert into EMPLOYEE_NAME
   (EMPLE_NO, STUDENT_NAME, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
 Values
   (21, 'KIM, BRANDY', 'BRANDY', 'KIM');
Insert into EMPLOYEE_NAME
   (EMPLE_NO, STUDENT_NAME, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME)
 Values
   (32, 'TRINA, JAMIE', 'JAMIE', 'TRINA');
```

Comment: You can cross join  DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW and  EMPLOYEE_NAME to get all possible pairs first. Next left join DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW to the above product.

Comment: Hello Serg, is this what your saying? The results are not correct. 
```
 SELECT DP.CLASS_DATE,
         VW.STUDENT_NAME,
         VW.EMPLE_NO,
         DP.FK_CLASS_NAME_ID
    FROM DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW DP
         CROSS JOIN EMPLOYEE_NAME VW
         LEFT JOIN DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW
             ON DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW.FK_CO_EMPL_ID = DP.FK_CO_EMPL_ID
ORDER BY STUDENT_NAME ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the following query works

**T1**: Lists all the courses and students that the student can choose.

**T2**: Lists all the courses and students that the student has chosen

*Then `T1` goes to `T2` **LEFT JOIN** with equal number of `PK_CLASS_NAME_ID` and `EMPLE_NO`*

```
SELECT 
    T1.STUDENT_NAME,
    T1.EMPLE_NO,
    T1.PK_CLASS_NAME_ID,
    T1.CLASS_NAME,
    T2.CLASS_DATE
FROM 
(
    SELECT VW.STUDENT_NAME,
           VW.EMPLE_NO,
           CN.PK_CLASS_NAME_ID,
           CN.CLASS_NAME 
    FROM TBL_CLASS_NAME_NEW CN 
      JOIN EMPLOYEE_NAME VW 
         ON 1=1
     GROUP BY VW.STUDENT_NAME,VW.EMPLE_NO, CN.PK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CN.CLASS_NAME 
) T1

LEFT JOIN

(
  
   SELECT  VW.STUDENT_NAME,
           VW.EMPLE_NO,
           CN.PK_CLASS_NAME_ID,
           CN.CLASS_NAME,
           DP.CLASS_DATE
   FROM TBL_CLASS_NAME_NEW CN 
     JOIN DEMO_PRODUCT_INFO_NEW DP
           ON CN.PK_CLASS_NAME_ID = DP.FK_CLASS_NAME_ID
     JOIN EMPLOYEE_NAME VW 
           ON DP.FK_CO_EMPL_ID = VW.EMPLE_NO
    GROUP BY  VW.STUDENT_NAME,VW.EMPLE_NO,CN.PK_CLASS_NAME_ID, CN.CLASS_NAME,DP.CLASS_DATE
) T2 ON T1.EMPLE_NO = T2.EMPLE_NO ANd T1.PK_CLASS_NAME_ID = T2.PK_CLASS_NAME_ID
```

I got the output in SQL, but it doesn't matter, it works in Oracle.

[image]

Comment: Those are the results that I am looking for. I see how you have the T1 then used the LEFT JOIN for T2. Looks really good thanks!